# AWS Textract: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I get this error while executing the AWS Tetxtract API .

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.(AmazonTextractClient.java:149)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.(AmazonTextractClient.java:133)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClientBuilder.build(AmazonTextractClientBuilder.java:61)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClientBuilder.build(AmazonTextractClientBuilder.java:27)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
>     at
>   com.tr.fundamental.s3FileUploader.AnalyzeDocument.main(AnalyzeDocument.java:177)

I have downloaded the latest Textract jar and included in my build path .
I do not get any compilation error ,but when i run i get this error at this point

```
  // Call AnalyzeDocument 
        EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration("https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "us-east-1");
        AmazonTextract client = AmazonTextractClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint).build();
```

My credential and all are correct and able to connect to S3 as well.
I am not sure what i am missing .
Please help

Answer (score 1):

A possible issue is that you are using difference artefact versions your aws libraries.

In case you are using Maven, have a look on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330900/2353294

Comment: Hi there, I see you are knowledgeable on this topic. Could you please help with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499160/aws-textract-key-value-pair-java-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me answer my question .
So using Default client solved my issue .

```
    EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration("https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "us-east-1");
    AmazonTextract client = AmazonTextractClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to version mismatch of aws sdk and textract. Keep same version, it would start working

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue, I have degraded the version and the issue get resolved.
It happens due to version mismatch.